# Cache warming in drupal7

Tags: caching, proxies

I have a drupal 7 website that uses Varnish for caching (through drupal's Varnish module).
 I want a cache warming mechanism that would automatically cache the latest version of the pages after the cache expiration time has passed.

How can i do this?

Comment: I don't actually understand what your question is. Also the varnish module doesn't provide any form of caching.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [cache warmer](http://drupal.org/project/cache_warmer) module, which apparently does just that.

There are also a bunch of blog posts on the topic around the web.